# is there a way to right click or simulate a ricket click in RSAT

Tags: dynamics-365

So I came up on a test in Dynamics where I need to right click on an option for the menu to appear and select. I noticed it doesn't the right click when recording as a step so I tried also shift+f10 but sadly same outcome. Is there another way to do this via RSAT (regression suite automation tool)?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't one unfortunately, I've been looking into this as I was looking to use RSAT to automate some refresh tasks and wasn't able to find a way for it to register as part of a task recording.